# bash - syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Tags: bash

I've got a script like this:

```
dyski=$(df -h)

while read wiersz; do

i=0;
for token in $wiersz
do

    case $i in
        0)
            tresc="$tresc\nSystem plików: $token";
        ;;

        1)
            tresc="$tresc\nRozmiar całkowity: $token";
        ;;

        2)
            tresc="$tresc\nUżyte miejsce : $token";
        ;;

        3)
            tresc="$tresc\nDostępne miejsce: $token";
        ;;

        4)
            tresc="$tresc\nProcentowe użycie: $token";
        ;;
    esac

    i=$((i+1))
done

tresc="$tresc\n"

done < <(echo "$dyski")
```

When I run it on my Mandriva, it works fine. But when I move it to the SLES11, it gives an error:

> ./diskcheck.sh: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
>   ./diskcheck.sh: line 42:`done < <(echo "$dyski")'

What's wrong with it? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Looks like you've got two "<" characters, buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you've made the mistake of assuming that `/bin/sh` is `bash` everywhere.  A number of Linux distributions use simpler shells (often `dash`, sometimes `ksh`) as `/bin/sh`; if you want to use `bash`-specific extensions such as `<(pipeline)` syntax, you should explicitly use `bash` as the shell.